# Unable to find libvirt documentation on installing to Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, uefi, raspberry

I've been looking for documentation for installing hypervisor libvirt to RaPi5. I've gathered some notes from various forums, however these steps will likely be problematic.

CLI install of qemu-kvm, libvirt-clients, libvirt-daemon-system and virt-manager. The CLI install might also need some special EFI settings, as I'm unsure if RaPi5 installs UEFI and is a 64-bit kernel?